# Erro na digitação

Tags: c

Eu peguei um livro de C para estudar, porém, ele está meio desatualizado, e me deparei com o seguinte código:

```
#include<stdio.h>

is_in(char *s, char c);

void main(void){
is_in("olac", "ola");
}

is_in(char *s, char c){
    while(*s)
        if(*s == c) return 1;
        else s++;
    return 0;
}
```

http://pastebin.com/raw/7dUSC0cj
alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Qual erro ele traz? Usa o code block que ele correge erro de simtaxe

Comment: Qual o problema ou dúvida sobre o trecho de código?

Answer (score 3):

Sobre erro de compilação, está faltando os tipos na no protótipo e na declaração da função:

```
int is_in(char *s, char c);
```

Na chamada do método, você está passando uma cadeia de caracteres ao invés de um char.

```
is_in("olac", "ola");
```

O GCC compila o código, mas não consegue transformar a cadeia inserida. O correto seria:

```
is_in("olac", 'o');
```

Lembrando que char sempre fica dentro de *plics* (').

E sobre o que o código faz: ele verifica se determinado carácter está presente dentro de uma cadeia de caracteres. Caso positivo, retorna 1 (true); 0 caso negativo (false).